# Executing a batch file via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, execute

So I'm trying to execute a .bat file from a JS code:

My HTML code includes:

```
<body dir=rtl onload="runExe()">
```

as my main.js JavaScript code is:

```
function runExe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = 'write.bat';
    shell.run(path,1,false);
}
```

The `write.bat` file adds a "success" word to a .txt file.
So far this code has no output to the text file. with a simple `alert('x')` command I realized that the code stops at the second line of JS code. Any ideas why? Is there something wrong with the ActiveXObject code?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does write.bat work if you run it by itself? BTW you realise ActiveX is dead technology? I'd highly recommend not writing any new code which uses it, if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: "Is there something wrong with the ActiveXObject code?" — It's unsupported in most browsers. Only IE ever supported it. I don't know if IE11 supports it.

Comment: I think the only mistake in your code is that `path` is not absolute and cmd can't find `write.bat`. Changed it to an absolute path like `D:\\write.bat` (remember to escape the \ character), and it worked for me in IE.

Comment: Thank you, all of you. I think that "technology" is indeed dead. I'm testing it on Chrome so that might be the reason. Any suggestions on how to code something like that?